# Can I access bike routes in Google maps?

Tags: android, iphone

Does the API give access to bike trails in Google maps? I need to be able to display existing bike maps on both Android and ios apps

Comment: The iOS SDK does not mention bike directions explicitly: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#directions

Answer (score 0):

There is no biking layer currently in maps v2, the only thing you can do is get biking directions.

Comment: I see the bicycling layer in the Javascript API v3. Does anyone have any information on how new this feature is, or if the v3 version for Android or iOS is due anytime soon?

Comment: well since v2 is relatively new I doubt there will be a v3 anytime soon. Javascript will be your only way to get the biking route right now